# datetime.parse and making it work with a specific format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a datetime coming back from an XML file in the format:

> 20080916 11:02

as in

> yyyymm hh:ss

How can I get the datetime.parse function to pick up on this? Ie parse it without erroring?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input,"yyyyMMdd HH:mm",null);
```

assuming you meant to say that minutes followed the hours, not seconds - your example is a little confusing.

The [ParseExact documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(VS.80).aspx) details other overloads, in case you want to have the parse automatically convert to Universal Time or something like that.

As @[Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) mentions, there's also the option of using [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(VS.80).aspx), which will return a Boolean value indicating success or failure of the operation - I'm still on .Net 1.1, so I often forget this one.

If you need to parse other formats, you can check out the [Standard DateTime Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Also: standard Xml has it's own very specific DateTime format, and the .Net Xml tools should be able to read it.

Comment: In this case it works ok with last parameter as null but for anyone who finds this CultureInfo.InvariantCulture otherwise you can get problems if your datetime is something like "1823/01/01".

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `standard XML specific DateTime format` ?

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for the tip, i used this to get my date "20071122" parsed, I needed to add datetimestyles, I used none and it worked:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

DateTime.TryParseExact("20071122", "yyyyMMdd", null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```