# Parse date string .net

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

What's the best way to convert a string such as:

```
Mon Nov 05 2012 21:27:58 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

in to a `DateTime` in .NET? I want to retain as much of the date as possible, i.e the TimeZone.

I'm trying this but it loses the `GMT`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date.Substring(0, 24),
                             "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a mix of `DateTimeOffset` (which conserves the the offset, but not the time-zone) and a string that represents the timezone. Depending on the format of the string, you might be able to parse the timezone as well.

Comment: Dupe of [datetime.parse and making it work with a specific format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format) ?

Comment: @lstern How is that a dupe? The issue here isn't just parsing the time, but the conserving offset&timezone as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sorry. You can strip the zone name and use the "zzzz" token as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/241885/1020222)

Comment: TimeZone is tricky as not part of DataTime.  Old link but still informative.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx Another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very robust, but it works for your example:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(date.Substring(0, 33) // remove time zone
                              .Remove(25,3)     // remove "GMT" before offset
                              ,"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
                              ,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You'll need `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` to preserve the offset. And of course you need to store the timezone separately.

Answer (score -1):

easy way to split the string and convert it into datetime using some formats. but what if some other formats comes to you.

try this one.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33298/C-Date-Time-Parser

sample

```
string str = @"Your program recognizes string : 21 Jun 2010 04:20:19 -0430 blah blah.";
DateTimeRoutines.ParsedDateTime pdt;
if(str.TryParseDateTime(DateTimeRoutines.DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE, out pdt) && pdt.IsUtcOffsetFound) 
Console.WriteLine("UTC date&time was found: " + pdt.UtcDateTime.ToString());
```