# String to DateTime Parsing

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm working on parsing few XML files where I have datetime values saved as text. I'm not able to find what format is the below one -

20110123T233356,00-05

I tried both `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTimeOffset.Parse` and both of them failed. I also tried to identify the string in few places like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format) with no luck.

Comment: Looks like it's yyyyMMddTHHmmss,xx-xx where xx-xx are numbers I have no idea about. What's the context?

Comment: @Rik - String is not recognized as a valid datetime.

Comment: I think your question is answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format

Comment: @rikitikitik: Looks like -05 is the UTC time zone offset, so the value after the comma may be `ff`.

Comment: @MehbubeArman - I've a 'T' here. In some places I read that it refers a timezone. Is it true?

Comment: Try DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - For ParseExact I need to pass the format which I'm trying to identify.

Comment: The `T` is there to separate the date from the time portion of the string.

Comment: @NLV Ref [ISO 8601 on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)

Comment: Without the last part '00-05' I'm able to parse. But how to include that UTC offset too as mentioned by @Aschratt ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the ",00" is hundredths of seconds and the "-05" is the timezone, you can parse it like this:

```
string dateStr = "20110123T233356,00-05";
string format = @"yyyyMMdd\THHmmss\,ffzz";

DateTime result;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Can't parse the date: " + dateStr);
}
```

However, that's a big assumption.

Note that you can also specify the format string without escaping the `T` or the `,` as follows (but I escaped them to make it more obvious that they aren't format characters):

```
string format = "yyyyMMddTHHmmss,ffzz";
```

Comment: Not a "big" assumption (it's by far the most likely case), but an assumption nonetheless.

Comment: Works perfectly. For now I will make that big assumption. Thank you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't need the slashes in the format string.

Comment: @Rik That's correct - I mention this at the end of my answer. I just like to make non-format characters more obvious by escaping them with slashes.