# How to parse date in datetime object?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

IDE: VS 2010, c# .net

I m having a textbox1 which is containg date

i.e

```
textbox1.text = "16/04/2014"
```

And I am having a datetime object

```
Datetime dt ;
dt = DateTime.Parse(textbox1.text);
//trying to set date in dt from the textbox1.text value
```

but it is returning String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. error.

pls tell the correct way.

Comment: That string seems to be in this format dd/MM/yyyy, if your locale settings are different then you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick in your format:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(textbox1.text);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the format your string is in, to get it parsed correctly.

You can use DateTime.ParseExact.

See this answer for more information:
Have a look at this answer:
[datetime.parse and making it work with a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format#341200)

Use

```
DateTime.ParseExact((textbox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.text, format,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```