# Month and Date stored the wrong way around in ASP to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

I am creating a C# ASP page that takes dates set by the users in a text box (the date is cheosen using a calendar object and then sent to the text box) and saves them to an SQL server.  When the dates are entered, it stores them in MM-DD-YYYY instead of DD-MM-YYYY.  This obviously generates errors!  Can anyone help me to get the dates to store them in the format I want it in?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime sevenDays = today.AddDays(7);
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;
        txtStart.Text = today.ToShortDateString();
        txtEnd.Text = sevenDays.ToShortDateString();
    }
    updateGrid();
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("MessageUpdateOrCreate", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageID", (hfMessageID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfMessageID.Value)));
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sender", txtSender.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Receiver", txtReceiver.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", txtMessage.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yeargroup", ddYear.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtStart.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry", txtEnd.Text.Trim());

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();
    string messageID = hfMessageID.Value;
    clear();

    if (messageID == "")
        lblSuccess.Text = "New message Success";
    else
        lblSuccess.Text = "Updated Success";
    updateGrid();
}
```

Comment: What's the field data type in SQL Server?

Comment: If your field's type are date, then you don't store them on MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY format, you store them on an internal binary (numerical) format. The MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY formats are applied by your application (your data components configuration) when you present that data.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is these two lines:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtStart.Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry", txtEnd.Text.Trim());
```

You are passing strings to a stored procedure that almost certainly expects a date. Which means the string will be converted to a date in a way you don't control.

So you need to take control. You need to parse the date in the way you need it to be (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy). These links will help you with that:

- [datetime.parse and making it work with a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format)
- https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DateParseExactAndTheSubtleGooThatIsDateTimeFormatStrings.aspx

Once you have parsed the string as a date:

1. Check that the date result is what you expected it to be
2. Pass that date (rather than the existing string) to the stored procedure

Comment: And use explicit parameter types instead of `AddWithValue`.