# How to parse DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

How can I parse this `DateTime` value?

> 17-09-2018 3:18

I want to parse the date and the time.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
x = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d/M/yyyy hh:MM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
x = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
x = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `MM` is months, `mm` is minutes. The casing matters. Double `m` or double `M` means the value always has 2 digits. A single `m` or single `M` means the value can have 1 digit if below `10`.

Comment: I'd go with `x = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime.parse and making it work with a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format)

Answer (score 5):

- `MM` is months, `mm` is minutes. The casing matters.
- Double `m` or double `M` means the value always has 2 digits. A single `m` or single `M` means the value can have 1 digit if below `10`.
- `H` means hours in military time (24 hour format), `h` means 12 hour with possible am/pm. The same rule applies for double digits.
- The character used between values has to match the input string, don't specify `-` if you are using `/` or the other way around. Alternativly use a culture parameter that has the same format specifier as in the input string.

```
 DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact("17-09-2018 3:18", "d-MM-yyyy h:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See also [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Technically `/` is the date separator in the format and the actual character it matches is based on the culture being used.

Comment: @juharr - `ParseExact` it will throw a `FormatException` if the separators in the input and format string don't match. Maybe there is an overload I have not considered?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator

Comment: @juharr - Interesting, thanks for the link. I just can't seem to get it to work with `DateTime.ParseExact` where a different `/` and `-` format specifier is used between the input and the format string. It always throws a `FormatException`. [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z2fSKG)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last comment. You can try [.NET Fiddle VEElcC](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VEElcC), modified from yours. When the culture uses `"-"` as its default date separator, the character `/` in the string `format` stands for this string, `"-"`.

Comment: My mistake was using a culture that had a / as a separator and doing the reverse @JeppeStigNielsen, thank you for the example code. It is clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just need to remember two more things:

1. **mm** is for minutes and **MM** is for month.
2. It's better to use **DateTime.TryParseExact** and not let the program throw exception interrupting the flow unless that is intended.

   ```
   // input string
   string dateString = "5/01/2009 09:00";

   // variable to hold output value
   DateTime dateValue;

   // specify all the valid formats here applicable in your case
   string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm", "d/M/yyyy hh:mm", "d/MM/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/MM/yy hh:mm", "dd/M/yy hh:mm", "d/M/yy hh:mm", "d/MM/yy hh:mm"};
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                      dateValue.Kind);
   ```