# TryParse not working properly to convert joined date like "270619"

Tags: c#, .net

The problem is to convert a random formatted (12/08/12-08-2019/12AUG/120819 etc) into DateTime. Since format is not fixed I'm using TryParse, it does work for normal cases but not for "120819".

```
string text="270619";

DateTime dt=new DateTime();

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IN");

var result=
DateTime.TryParse(text,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out dt);

Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Expected date should be 27-06-2019 00:00:00

Edit:
Currently I'm using formats={"ddMMyy","ddMMyyyy"} and its working, but TryParseExact then fails for the other format like dd-MM-yyyy. Guess I need to write down all the possible formats in there. Or use if else case using both TryParse and TryParseExact.

Comment: How can it parse that without knowing what the format is?  120819 could be 12th august 2019 or 8th december 2019 depending on who you ask (it could of course be 1919 but thats a different matter)..  The only way is to tell it what the format is, either ddMMyy or MMddyy

Comment: TryParse doesn't guess more than Parse does, it just doesn't throw an exception. Use TryParseExact and pass the appropriate format. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format) (one of many, this question basically gets asked once a day), and [Microsoft Docs: Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: What date are you actually getting? And what is in `result` if you debug it?

Comment: if the format is not fixed, then basically you can't parse it.

Comment: @PeterSmith its the default date 01-01-0001 00:00:00

Comment: @TimRutter the format would always be like date-month-year but in different formats like ddMMyy or ddMMyyyy or ddMMM etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `TryParseExact` and provide your format `ddMMyy` like this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "ddMMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                      System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Comment: Currently I'm using formats={"ddMMyy","ddMMyyyy"} and its working, but TryParseExact then fails for the other format like dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: You need to have all possibilities in your `formats` array. Treat those as your accepted formats. Otherwise, you could use Regex to format the string yourself before trying to parse it, but that's an extra step.

Comment: Thanks @dvo. I might just use both TryParse and TryParseExact one after another to avoid writing all the formats bc there are many.

Comment: Sounds like a very bug prone approach to me.  Why is it that you have so many format possibilities?