# Parse DateTime with special format using C#

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, format

I would like to parse a datetime string with a special format.

Unfortunately I get an error. The datetime string is like the following: "08012020 21:17:05".

I tried the following code sample:

`if (DateTime.TryParse(strDateTime, out dtDateTime)) 
       Print(strDateTime + " --> " + dtDateTime);
   else
       Print("Unable to parse DateTime " + strDateTime );`

Any ideas how to parse the special format?

Gerik

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime.parse and making it work with a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341175/datetime-parse-and-making-it-work-with-a-specific-format) ... which is second goolge resutl for the title of your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) methods to *specific* exact format if a your string is *not* a standard date format of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8) settings.

The "proper" format seems like `ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss` with a "proper" culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.8) as;

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateTime, "ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvarianCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dtDateTime))
{
   // Print
}
```